# Erro na implementação do PagSeguro

Tags: php, javascript

### Explicação

Estou tentando implementar o Checkout Web por redirecionamento do PagSeguro em meu site de testes, no entanto, ao clicar no botão, permaneço recebendo esse erro no console como no print abaixo, e não há qualquer resposta no clique.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o Netlify pra *hostear* esse site pois já me dá um certificado HTTPS automaticamente.

O site em questão é: https://epic-benz-ab8c6a.netlify.com/

### Código

Os códigos sem email e token sandbox também podem ser acessados [nesse repositório](https://github.com/projectssome/pagseguro-sandbox).

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>API Pagseguro</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form name="FormPagamento" id="FormPagamento" action="https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="iot" value="button" />
        <input id="BotaoPagamento" type="image" src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/public/img/botoes/pagamentos/209x48-pagar-azul-assina.gif" name="submit" alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!" />
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Libraries/Javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript.js**

```
var Root = "http://" + document.location.hostname + "/";

$('#BotaoPagamento').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: Root + "Controllers/ControllerPagamentoDireto.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#code').val(data);
            $('#FormPagamento').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

**ControllerPagamentoDireto.php**

```
<?php
    $Data["email"]="meuemail@email.com";
    $Data["token"]="meutoken";
    $Data["currency"]="BRL";
    $Data["itemId1"]="1";
    $Data["itemDescription1"]="Site de testes";
    $Data["itemAmount1"]="1000.00";
    $Data["itemQuantity1"]="1";
    $Data["itemWeight1"]="1000";
    $Data["reference"]="1010";
    $Data["senderName"]="Nome do Comprador";
    $Data["senderAreaCode"]="21";
    $Data["senderPhone"]="99999999";
    $Data["senderEmail"]="emailsandboxcomprador@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br";
    $Data["shippingType"]="1";
    $Data["shippingAddressStreet"]="Avenida Rio Branco";
    $Data["shippingAddressNumber"]="100";
    $Data["shippingAddressComplement"]="Apartamento";
    $Data["shippingAddressDistrict"]="Centro";
    $Data["shippingAddressPostalCode"]="20040004";
    $Data["shippingAddressCity"]="Rio de Janeiro";
    $Data["shippingAddressState"]="RJ";
    $Data["shippingAddressCountry"]="BRA";
    $BuildQuery=http_build_query($Data);
    $Url="https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout";
    $Curl=curl_init($Url);
    curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1"));
    curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
    curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$BuildQuery);
    $Retorno=curl_exec($Curl);
    curl_close($Curl);
    $Xml=simplexml_load_string($Retorno);
    echo $Xml->code;
?>
```

Comment: kd o print?....

Comment: Desculpa! Havia esquecido de colocar a imagem. Já editei a pergunta com ela.

Comment: O erro 404 diz que não está achando o caminho `https://epic-benz-ab8c6a.netlify.com/Controllers/ControllerPagamentoDireto.php`

Comment: Mas supostamente o endereço estaria certo, não? O Netlify usa o meu repositório do Github para gerar o site, e lá está divido em pastas, tendo o `ControllerPagamentoDireto.php` esse endereço final. Desculpa qualquer coisa! Sou novo com php e javascript, to quebrando a cabeça procurando e tentando soluções próprias, mas nada deu certo até agora :(

Comment: Eu troquei de http para https em `var Root = "http://" + document.location.hostname + "/";` no script, já que o domínio é https, mas nada mudou. Ao entrar em `https://epic-benz-ab8c6a.netlify.com/Controllers/ControllerPagamentoDireto.php` o php é baixado, tanto em https quanto em http.

Comment: Parece que o domínio não interpreta php, pq tá baixando o arquivo em vez de processar.

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Pelo o que pesquisei, o Netlify interpreta php na inicialização, mas não após o site ter carregado. Obrigado!